# Would observed limit on resonant double Higgs production the same if the scenario considered is spin $0$ scalar or spin $0$ radion particle?

Tags: higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

At LHC, some analyses search for resonant HH production, from an unknown particle labelled $X$. They typically make the limit on cross-section of resonant HH production as a function of the spin of the unknown particle $X$ : spin $0$ and spin $2$. They overlap the theoretical cross-section of the model with a given spin.

(
Consider for example :
https://cds.cern.ch/record/2853597/files/HIG-21-005-pas.pdf
)

Would limit the same if the scenario is spin $0$ scalar particle or if it is spin $0$ [radion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviscalar) particle ?

Would the theoretical cross-section overlapped be different if the scenario is spin $0$ scalar particle or if it is spin $0$ radion particle ?

If they would be different, why don't they consider also the case spin $0$ scalar Higgs particle ? (of course with a mass different to $125$ GeV)

Comment: Presumably the correct answer is that all the spin 0 possibilities behave the same, because they all obey the same equation, the Klein-Gordon equation.

Comment: Since radion and Higgs are distinct I guess that result should change, else why would we search for radion

Comment: Assuming you mean the possibility of a second Higgs... Radion scenario and second Higgs scenario can both cause resonant production of original Higgs, while differing in some other way (e.g. interactions with non-Higgs particles). There are many possibilities and a single experiment may only be able to distinguish between one class of theory and another class of theory, you need further experiments to get even more nuanced evidence... Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one else is tackling this...

[The report from CMS at CERN](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2853597/files/HIG-21-005-pas.pdf) is about looking for production of pairs of Higgs bosons. In the introduction, they say this could be enhanced beyond what occurs in the standard model, by the creation of a heavy scalar "X" that then decays into two Higgs bosons.

As examples, they list three theoretical scenarios: a [Randall-Sundrum "radion"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0009232); a [heavy scalar from a two-Higgs-doublet model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0034) (2HDM); and a [Randall-Sundrum bulk graviton](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905221). But in figure 18 (page 24), they only plot expectations for two possibilities, the radion and the graviton. These are presented as representative of two scenarios for X, spin 0 and spin 2.

So the question is asked, do they not bother with the 2HDM scalar, because it's also spin-0, and therefore behaves exactly the same as the spin-0 radion?

My *suspicion* is that this is so, and that for the purposes of this experiment, the two theoretical possibilities (Randall-Sundrum and 2HDM) both reduce to the same scenario of "standard model plus heavy scalar X with an XHH coupling".

But I could be wrong. If you look at the linked 2HDM reference, it discusses a plethora of models; maybe they didn't have a 2HDM plot because there are many possibilities, but most of them only differ a little from the radion scenario, so the radion can serve as a prototypical example of what happens when X is spin 0.

I'll edit this, if I find reasons for a more decisive answer. Meanwhile, you could always write to someone at CMS if you want an authoritative reply!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry for the delay. I wanted to check everything.